# Finding the distribution of a function of random variable

Tags: probability, functions, reliability

Let's say that Y = aX1 + bX2 + cX3 where all the random variables (X1, X2 and X3) are normally distributed. How can I find the distribution of the function Z = e^Y?

The mean and variance of X1, X2 and X3 are given as N(1,0.3), N(4.1,0.4) and N(6,0.6) respectively.

Comment: What have you tried? Are the $X_i$ independent? What is the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: @Henry I have assumed them to be independent. Distribution of Y is N(1.865,1.16)

Comment: You might want to read about log-normal distributions

Comment: You can find the density of $e^Y$ by using the change of variables theorem, or by dofferentiating the CDF.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to solve the problem. A normally distributed random variable (I am assuming you mean one-dimensional) has a mean and a variance, neither of which you mention. If you mean that each X_j has mean 0 and variance 1, that is called a *standard* normal random variable. *Also*: When you mention several random variables that are being somehow combined, it's necessary to state how they relate to each other in their joint distribution. Let me guess: You want the X_j, 1 ≤ j ≤ 3 to be *independent* of each other. In which case it's important to say that.

Answer (score 0):

If $Y\sim N(m,\sigma^2)$ then $\Pr(e^Y<z)=\Pr (Y<\log z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\log z}e^{-(y-m)^2/2\sigma^2}\frac{dy}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and the density of $Z=e^Y$ is $e^{-(\log z-m)^2/2\sigma^2}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\times \frac{1}{z}$ from the fundamental theorem of calculus and the derivative of composition of functions. If $Y=a_1X_1+a_2X_2+a_3X_3 $ where $X_i\sim N(m_i,\sigma_i^2)$ all independent then $m=a_1m_1+a_2m_2+a_3m_3$ and $\sigma^2=a_1^2\sigma_1^2+a_2^2\sigma_2^2+a_3^2\sigma_3^2.$